# Unable to grab the element which is loaded using Load() method from parent Element

Tags: jquery

i am quite a newbie to JQuery. I have loaded an html element with some Pics in it using

```
$('#productsContainer').load('productsThumbs.aspx');
```

Now, the `productsThumbs.aspx` file contains images with class `.thumbs`.
Now i can not find that element using jquery from my parent element.
Can some one please help me with it?
i tried using `.thumbs` from parent element but it returns nothing. 
thanks.

Comment: Could you show us how you select on it?

Comment: $('.productthumbs').click(function () {  like this..

Comment: if it's called `.thumbs` the class you're using then I'm assuming you want to do this `$('#productsContainer .thumbs')`.

Comment: that much of code wont help. plz show some code

Comment: ok i have Something like this in thumbs page    <div id="gallery">
            <img class="productthumbs" data-src="../../images/denim4.jpg" />

Comment: Perhaps your ajax call is not yet complete when you try to access the elements. Use `$('#productsContainer').load('productsThumbs.aspx', function() { .. do stuff ...} );` to handle the `complete` event

Comment: And i use this now ut it still don't work.         $('#productsContainer .productthumbs').click(function () {
            alert('Cliked');

Comment: No Dom Day, it is not working.:(

Comment: hmm, ok, do you ever set the `src` of the `img` elements from the `data-src` property ? more code might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding your click event in the `complete` handler, like so:

```
$('#productsContainer').load('productsThumbs.aspx', function() { 
    $('#productsContainer .productthumbs').click(function () {alert('Click');} );
});
```

edit: requested explanation

The `load()` call is "asynchronous", meaning that while it does its work, your code will continue. This means the operation may not be complete when you try to manipulate the data it returns.

The function we have added is a "callback", which will run when the load operation completes. If you perform your manipulation here, you can be sure that the elements you are working on exist ( assuming the load was successful )

It is similar to the callbacks you might have used in jQuery animation.

Comment: Thanks it Worked, can you explain a bit about this code, thanks.

Comment: Also, depending on your version of jQuery (1.8+) you should use `on()` for binding the click as it binds to all present and future elements! :)

Comment: @limelights : yah, personally, I always use `on()`, although `click()` isn't deprecated ( like `die()` ), it's just a shortcut jquery converts to `on()`